# $_GET['callback'] not working when using crossdomain

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain

I using jsonP and crossdomain, processing send request working but i can't get $_GET['callback']. It return NULL any one help me. Thanks 
this is my code

```
$jq.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonP',
        type : 'post',
        data : data,
        crossDomain: true,

        beforeSend: function(){
            showLoadingAnimation();

        },
        success: function(data){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sample is correct, you send a request of type "POST" and asking for a $_GET variable in the backend. Use $_POST['callback']

Comment: Thanks your anwers. I have used $_POST['callback'] but it not working. Before i using $_GET['callback'] It got value. I don't know why it not working now. you know other reason Please help me

Comment: your example doesn't show, how you set a value for "callback" please add this code or notice, what value you would expect